# Using JSON, display all images into UICollectionView from web directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I'm new to iOS dev and need a UICollectionView to display all images in async within a folder on my webserver.

Let's say the folder is: www.website1.com/img/new/

I will have a JSON file that shows text and an image pertaining to that text. Something really basic like:

```
{"Items":[
{"URL":"URL.com/img1.jpg", "TEXT":"TEXT1"},
{"URL":"URL.com/img2.jpg", "TEXT":"TEXT2"},
{"URL":"URL.com/img3.jpg", "TEXT":"TEXT3"}]}
```

The code simply needs to parse the JSON and update accordingly. What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: `NSJSONSerialization` to parse the JSON, then you can use `SDWebImage`, `AFNetworking`, etc which implement a category on `UIImageView` to load the image asynchronously or do it yourself.

Comment: Your post show no effort from your side to solve this yourself. This might get you question downvoted and closed.

Comment: The reason was simply because I wanted some sort of snippet or good starting point. This type of processing is very common and there must be tools out there already pre-programmed. I was just querying to see if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks for your reply i'll look into these!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create object form your flux Json
2. Create and fill data source of your collection , this data source contain all objects
3. Custom your UICollectionViewCell (imageView)
4. Manage downloading image since CellView (use cache)
5. See this article for asynchrone download https://www.appcoda.com/ios-concurrency

hope it help.